# How can I make bash select an empty colum?

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I have two tables in a database which allows each email address in the database to upload a maximum of 14 files. How can I make bash select an empty column to allow the upload of a file?

Thanks in advance.

The two tables are called uploadid and uploadurl.

Here are the two tables:

**Table 1 - Upload IDs (Upload Names)**

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| email_address  | varchar(256) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| 1_upload_id    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 2_upload_id    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 3_upload_id    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 4_upload_id    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 5_upload_id    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 6_upload_id    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 7_upload_id    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 8_upload_id    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 9_upload_id    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 10_upload_id   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 11_upload_id   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 12_upload_id   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 13_upload_id   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 14_upload_id   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Table 2 - Upload URLs (Link of the uploaded file)**

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| email_address  | varchar(256) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| 1_upload_url   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 2_upload_url   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 3_upload_url   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 4_upload_url   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 5_upload_url   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 6_upload_url   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 7_upload_url   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 8_upload_url   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 9_upload_url   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 10_upload_url  | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 11_upload_url  | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 12_upload_url  | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 13_upload_url  | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 14_upload_url  | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by the output?

Answer (score 0):

The design of your database is very bad but nevermind... you could try something like :

```
query = "SELECT"
for i in {1..14}; do
    query="$query COALESCE(${i}_upload_id, 'freeSpace') AS idFile${i}"
done
query="$query FROM table1 WHERE email = '$email';"

result=$(echo $query|mysql -u<user> -p<password> <dbname>)
[[ $result =~ freeSpace ]] && echo "$email can upload files" || echo "$email can't upload files"
```

That's an example of what could be done with Bash, but I'm not sure that's the best technology for what you want to do.

Otherwise, here is an example of more smart design of your database :

```
User(id, email) 
    => PK constraint on column "id" (auto_increment)
    => UNIQUE constraint on column "email"

File(id_file, uri_file, id_user)
    => PK constraint  on column "id_file"
    => FK constraint on column "id_user" (references User.id)
```

And to know if an user is able to upload a new file, you could run this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(id_file) AS nbFiles FROM File WHERE id_user = (SELECT id FROM User WHERE email = '$email');
```

And if nbFiles >= 14, the user will not be able to upload a new file ;)

Comment: Can you suggest me a better table design? Thanks.